# If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A$ is closed, is there some continuous function $f : X\to \mathbb{R}$ whose zero set is $A$?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a metric space, then this is easy: take $f(x) = d(x, A).$ But if $X$ is a generic compact Hausdorff space, is this still true? I can't seem to think of a reason why it should hold, but I expect it too.

Comment: Let $X$ be a space that satisfies one of the following equivalent conditions: 1) for all $E$ closed there is $f:X\to\Bbb R$ continuous such that $f^{-1}(0)=E$; 2) $X$ normal and every closed set is $G_\delta$ (Vedenissoff theorem); 3) for all closed $E\ne X$ there is some closed $F\ne\emptyset$ such that $E\cap F=\emptyset$ and for all $E,F$ disjoint closed there is some $f:X\to\Bbb R$ continuous such that $f^{-1}(0)=E$ and $f^{-1}(1)=F$. Such a space is called *perfectly normal* (or $T_{5\frac12}$). Perfectly normal Hausdorff is $T_6$.

Comment: See https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=compact%20%2B%20%24T_2%24%20%2B%20~%24T_6%24 for examples of compact Hausdorff non-$T_6$ spaces, namely $[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology and $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Now that I think about it, in condition (2) the fact that for all $E\ne X$ there is some closed $F\ne\emptyset$ such that $E\cap F=\emptyset$ is unnecessary, because it already follows from the other condition specialised to $F=\emptyset$. Turns out wikipedia wasn't wrong after all.